# ListView закрывает все элементы, как этого избежать?

Tags: android, listview

У меня есть Activity с ListView и с кнопками в самом низу. Как мне сделать так, чтобы прокручивался только ListView, а не весь Activity, и чтобы не пропадали кнопки внизу экрана.

Код Activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/activity_main_start"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Start" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/activity_main_stop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Stop" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/activity_main_clear"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Clean" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/activity_main_refresh"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Refresh" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Обновление**

Если я помещаю кнопки вверху экрана, то список не получается, всё так, как мне надо. (Список прокручивается, но экран вместе с ним не прокручивается и кнопки находятся вверху). А мне надо, чтобы было так же, но кнопки были внизу.

Comment: @BORSHEVIK, сделайте главный слой - RelativeLayout: слой с кнопками привяжите как `layout_alignParentBottom`, у Listview уберите внешний слой (он не нужен) и сделайте ему `layout_above`.

Comment: Я прошу прощения, но как раз я в этом не силён, не могли бы вы дать код пример, как это выглядит?

Конкретно про "layout_alignParentBottom, у Listview уберите внешний слой (он не нужен) и сделайте ему layout_above."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Теперь кнопки всегда видны, скролится только `ListView`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layout_btns">
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_btns"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/activity_main_start"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Start"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/activity_main_stop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Stop"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/activity_main_clear"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Clean"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/activity_main_refresh"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Refresh"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```